# jquery change text input with content of var

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to put together a Jquery & JQ ui slider that calculates the subranges and after that update the content of 2 divs and 2 textboxes, my only problem is that i don't get the VAR in the textbox while im sliding the "slider".

I want to have it returned to the inputs with #hidden1&2 and to the divs with the #slider-results1&2 but i dont know howto do that with VAR A for example. On slide he needs to calculate and then update the INPUT and DIV with the results from A B and C.

So if anybody can explain what might could work or whatever im doing wrong it could be very helpfull

Jsfiddle can be found here, dont change it pls: http://jsfiddle.net/m5mpkang/49/

my code so far:

```
$(function () {
var myslider = $('#basic').limitslider({
    values: [100, 200],
    min: 0,
    max: 300,
    step: 0.5,
    showRanges: true,
    left: 7,
    ranges: [false, true, false],

    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( '#slider-result1' ).html( ui.values[0] );
    $( '#slider-result2' ).html( ui.values[1] );
    $( '#amount1' ).val( ui.values[0] );
    $( '#amount2' ).val( ui.values[1] );
    var z=$( '#amount1' ).val();
    var y=$( '#amount2' ).val();
    var x=300; // fixed @ 300, future use: <?=$php->size?>
    var a=z;   // subrange between the begin / selector 1
    var b=y-z; // subrange between selector 1 / 2
    var c=x-y; // subrange between selector 2 / MAX
    $('#hidden1').html(a); 
    $('#hidden1').attr('value', 'a'); /// this "a" refers to VAR A and VAR A gets it from VAR Z
    $('#hidden2').attr('value', ui.values[1]); /// this works due but aint the plan cause i need the calculated VARS
    },

   });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by calculated VARS?

Comment: the VARS: var c=x-y;

Comment: Sorry, It's unclear to me what you're asking...

Comment: i need to display the content of VAR a to the textbox with #hidden1  with $('#hidden1').attr('value', 'a') BUT "a" doesnt refers to the VAR

Comment: go look the js fidle then and look for yourself what it does, pls read the full question and look @ the fiddle before asking anythin. go think yourself, im not good with english so its hard for me to explain what i mean

Comment: I know what you are asking, i have created it, but right now I am unable to ans because I am not at my system and I forgot how I done it.

Comment: In your example z isn't defined. You set it to `$( '#amount1' ).val()` but there is no field with an ID of amount1.

Also the line `$('#hidden1').attr('value', 'a');` is setting the value to a string 'a', not to the value of the variable called a.

It should be `$('#hidden1').val(a);` (notice the lack of quotes around a).

Comment: THAT DOESNT MATTER GO LOOK THE JS FIDDLE AND SEE WHAT IT DOES

Comment: .val( ui.values[0] );

Comment: OK that is something that i can check out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of variables doing the same thing, which I think is were your confusion lies.

You are really just interested in `ui.values[0]` and `ui.values[1]` so put them in a variable first and go from there:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    // store the values once and use them whenever you need to
    var z = ui.values[0];
    var y = ui.values[1];

    $('#slider-result1' ).html(z);
    $('#slider-result2' ).html(y);
    $('#amount1').val(z);
    $('#amount2').val(y);

    var x=300; // fixed @ 300, future use: <?=$php->size?>
    var b=y-z; // subrange between selector 1 / 2
    var c=x-y; // subrange between selector 2 / MAX

    $('#hidden1').html(z); 
    $('#hidden1').attr('value', z); // don't put a in quotes, it's a variable
    $('#hidden2').attr('value', y);
},
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5mpkang/52/)

Comment: YOU NEED A FOCKING MEDAL FOR THE BEST ANSWER!